# Authorization Bearer Token for Cloud Vision API

Tags: firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions, bearer-token, google-cloud-vision

## Problem

I've written a cloud function that takes a base64 string and passes it into the Google Cloud Vision API, and I've also written a function on the client that calls a Firebase Cloud Function via HTTP.

Although the data passes along well from the client to the Cloud Function, the request to the Google Vision API from the server doesn't work. I get a status code `500` error.

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the Authorization bearer token, because running this in the shell with the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` works just fine. By the way, the same environment variable is present when running the Cloud Function.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate
```

Am I using the correct bearer token (see code below)? How would I be able to get this request to go through?

### Client Side

```js
auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
        .then((idToken) => {
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:5001/project/my-endpoint',
            data: qs.stringify({
              imageData: image,
              token: idToken
            }),
            maxContentLength: 100000,
            maxBodyLength: 100000
          }) // .then, .catch follows...
        })
```

### Server Side

```js
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${request.body.token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        data: {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "image": {
                        "content": request.body.imageData   
                    },
                    "features": [
                        {
                            "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        maxContentLength: 100000,
        maxBodyLength: 100000
    }) // .then, .catch follows...
```

Comment: A 500 error from Cloud Vision wouldn't normally indicate an authentication or authorization issue. Or do you mean that your server is returning 500 to your client?  Are you sure the image data is not corrupt?

Comment: @EricSchoen The API returns 500 to the server. The image data definitely isn't corrupt—I ran the same image data through the command line and it worked as expected.

Comment: Any useful content in the body of the 500 response?

Comment: @EricSchoen No, not anything useful.

Comment: It worked for me using what you're trying:  Authorization: Bearer {{token}} where {{token}} was what was printed by gcloud auth application-default print-access-token. I tried a bad token, and got a 401 response.  I tried a personal token (not service account) and got a 403 response.  With a good token, I tried base 64 encoding the image data, and got a 200 response with an error for bad image data.  I had to leave the image data as a byte array... but I'm exercising this from Clojure and not node/axios.  But I wasn't able to provoke a 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use the [client library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#documentTextDetection). The docs on Google's page aren't so great, but these docs are much better.

The code should look something like this:

```js
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision')
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

const fileName = request.body.imageData // base64 image data

    const req = {
        image: {
            content: fileName
        }
    }

    client.documentTextDetection(req)
        .then(result => response.send(result))
        .catch(error => response.send(error))
})
```